# mySQL column to hold array

Tags: mysql, arrays

I'm a beginner concerning coding and especially SQL and PHP.
I deal with app. 120 users.
The users can acquire app. 300 different collectible items.
When a user acquires a specific item, I would like the ID number of that particular item to be stored in the row of the user who acquired it, so that there is some information about what items the user already has (and to avoid duplicate items in his possession).
Is there a good way to store such information?
Is it even possible to set a column type to array and store it there?

Please note: I'm not lazy and I've been digging around and searching for the answer for 2 hours. I couldn't find a solution. I know of the rule that one should insert only one piece of information into one cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not support storing arrays. However, you can use a second table to emulate an array by storing the relation between the users and items. Say you have the table `users`:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);
```

And you have a table defining `items`:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    item_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);
```

You can relate what items a user has using a table similar to `user_items`:

```
CREATE TABLE user_items (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    item_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ...,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES users (user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (item_id)
        REFERENCES items (item_id)
);
```

Then, to determine what items user `123` has acquired, you could use *JOIN*s similar to:

```
SELECT items.*
FROM users
INNER JOIN user_items
    ON user_items.user_id = users.user_id
INNER JOIN items
    ON items.item_id = user_items.item_id
WHERE users.user_id = 123; -- Or some other condition.
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have 2 tables for example, users and items. To control which user already has a specific item, i would create an associative table, including the `UserID` from `users` and `ItemID` from `items`. This way you can now check in your `user_items` table if the user already has this item.

Here is a small example:

users (UserID is PK): 
`+--------+----------+
| UserID | UserName |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | Fred     |
|      2 | Joe      |
+--------+----------+`

items (ItemID is PK): 
`+---------+----------+
| ItemID  | ItemName |
+---------+----------+
|       5 | Book     |
|       6 | Computer |
+---------+----------+`

user_items (`ItemID` referencing `items.ItemID`, `UserID` referencing `users.UserID`): 
`+---------+--------+
| ItemID  | UserID |
+---------+--------+
|       5 |      1 |
|       6 |      2 |
+---------+--------+`