# Structure table to hold array - mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a PhoneNumber table that looks like:

```
contactType| country | areaCode| exchangeCode| localNumber| id| createdDate| lastModifiedDate| createdBy| lastModifiedBy|
```

an Address table that looks like:

```
contactType| street1 | street2| city| state| zip| country| id| createdDate| lastModifiedDate| createdBy| lastModifiedBy|
```

and a person table looks like:

```
| id | firstName | lastName | email | birthdate  | phoneNumbers | addresses | gender | createdDate | lastModifiedDate | createdBy     | lastModifiedBy
```

note: the phoneNumbers and addresses are foreign keys that point to the ids of phoneNumber and Address respectively.

My Question: How can I get the person with the address and phonenumbers in there? I know that it will require JOIN somehow but I don't know how.

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26872445/mysql-column-to-hold-array), but i'm confused on how/why the JOIN works in there.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, and you want to simply list all the fields in each table in relation to a "person" (I'll leave out the three metadata fields at the end of each table), you'll want something like:

```
select p.id, p.firstName, p.lastName, p.email, p.birthdate,
    pn.contactType, pn.country, pn.areaCode, pn.exchangeCode, pn.localNumber,
    a.contactType, a.street1, a.street2, a.city, a.state, a.zip, a.country
from person p
inner join PhoneNumber pn
on p.id = pn.id
inner join address a
on p.id = a.id
```

If "country" and "contactType" are the same in both tables, you could omit one or the other, or join on these fields if multiple contactTypes/countries can exist for a single ID.